# Can't vote or follow certain links on meta

Tags: bug, status-completed

On the main site I'm able to vote on posts and view vote breakdowns, but on meta it's not letting me do so. Also, clicking the inbox and achievements buttons in the top bar don't do anything on meta but work fine on the main site.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Derp derp, that's my bad. Fixed now.

We recently moved all styles and images for sites from `/content` to `/content/sites`, and I thought it might be a good idea to do a search & replace in out DB creation script... which turned out to have been a bad idea. I updated the broken site setting on the main site here shortly after the launch, and completely forgot that meta would be afflicted in the same way.

The script is also fixed now, so future launches should go off without a hitch. (Or at least without this particular hitch.)

Comment: \o/ Thanks so much, Adam!

Comment: Thanks for fessing up, Adam... and thanks for the quick fix. Where do we send the thank you beer? :)

Comment: @Flimzy I wouldn't set up a beer incentive for me to "accidentally" mess up in the future if I were you. ;)